# `/dev/fuse` is huge

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, disk-usage

I am running a bit low on storage. After running `df -h` I saw the following:

```
/dev/fuse       250G   512  250G   1%
```

Should I try to shrink it? Is it ok for the `/dev/fuse` to be that large?

Please note, that I run on Windows + Ubuntu 20.04 dual-boot, so maybe it is Windows. I have 1TB SSD on my laptop, but the sum of all the sizes of the output of  `df -h` is definitely less than 1TB, so probably it is not.

EDIT: after restarting the system, the `/dev/fuse` disappeared for some reason.

full output of `df -h`:

```
udev            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  2.4M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p6   83G   65G   14G  83% /
tmpfs           7.7G  306M  7.4G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2      209M  209M     0 100% /snap/code/74
/dev/loop4      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11420
/dev/loop3      209M  209M     0 100% /snap/code/75
/dev/loop6       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2074
/dev/loop1      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop5      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11606
/dev/loop7      242M  242M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/70
/dev/loop8       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1081
/dev/loop9       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1026
/dev/loop0      1.3M  1.3M     0 100% /snap/axel/77
/dev/loop10     219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
/dev/loop11     219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
/dev/loop13     768K  768K     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/726
/dev/loop12     2.5M  2.5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/884
/dev/loop14     640K  640K     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/103
/dev/loop15      33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12883
/dev/loop16     243M  243M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/76
/dev/loop17     384K  384K     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/708
/dev/nvme0n1p1  256M   35M  222M  14% /boot/efi
/dev/loop18     2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/157
/dev/loop19      56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2128
/dev/nvme0n1p7  153G  140G  5.0G  97% /home
/dev/loop20     2.5M  2.5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/826
/dev/loop21     256K  256K     0 100% /snap/jq/6
/dev/loop22      33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/13170
/dev/loop23     308M  308M     0 100% /snap/telegram-desktop/3149
/dev/loop24      51M   51M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/547
/dev/loop25      66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
/dev/loop26      66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/loop27     640K  640K     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/106
/dev/loop28     223M  223M     0 100% /snap/pinta-james-carroll/8
/dev/loop29      27M   27M     0 100% /snap/heroku/4068
/dev/loop30     308M  308M     0 100% /snap/telegram-desktop/3119
/dev/loop31      27M   27M     0 100% /snap/heroku/4076
/dev/loop32     2.5M  2.5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/163
tmpfs           1.6G   88K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Full output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.2 MiB, 1253376 bytes, 2448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 208.43 MiB, 218542080 bytes, 426840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 208.43 MiB, 218546176 bytes, 426848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 99.39 MiB, 104210432 bytes, 203536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 99.35 MiB, 104169472 bytes, 203456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 55.45 MiB, 58134528 bytes, 113544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 241.37 MiB, 253087744 bytes, 494312 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.89 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: WDC PC SN730 SDBQNTY-1T00-1001          
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 09126438-D691-4D3B-BDF1-AC5099BB812D

Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     534527     532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2     534528     567295      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3     567296 1486360575 1485793280 708.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 1998360576 2000408575    2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 1486360576 1496125439    9764864   4.7G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p6 1496125440 1672187903  176062464    84G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p7 1672187904 1998360575  326172672 155.5G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/loop8: 61.79 MiB, 64770048 bytes, 126504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 61.75 MiB, 64729088 bytes, 126424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 218.102 MiB, 229629952 bytes, 448496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 2.5 MiB, 2605056 bytes, 5088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 704 KiB, 720896 bytes, 1408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 548 KiB, 561152 bytes, 1096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop15: 32.31 MiB, 33869824 bytes, 66152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop16: 242.35 MiB, 254115840 bytes, 496320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop17: 276 KiB, 282624 bytes, 552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop18: 2.24 MiB, 2342912 bytes, 4576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop19: 55.45 MiB, 58130432 bytes, 113536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop20: 2.49 MiB, 2600960 bytes, 5080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop21: 240 KiB, 245760 bytes, 480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop22: 32.32 MiB, 33878016 bytes, 66168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop23: 307.46 MiB, 322387968 bytes, 629664 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop24: 50.98 MiB, 53432320 bytes, 104360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop25: 65.22 MiB, 68378624 bytes, 133552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop26: 65.1 MiB, 68259840 bytes, 133320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop27: 548 KiB, 561152 bytes, 1096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop28: 222.2 MiB, 232800256 bytes, 454688 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop29: 26.24 MiB, 27504640 bytes, 53720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop30: 307.48 MiB, 322404352 bytes, 629696 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop31: 26.24 MiB, 27512832 bytes, 53736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop32: 2.51 MiB, 2621440 bytes, 5120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: `/dev/fuse` shouldn't occupy more than 4KB, it's just a device node. Please edit your question and include the full output of `df -h` and `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thank you so much! 

I have restarted the system. Now the `df -h` does not contain the `dev/fuse` at all . But from the output of `sudo fdisk -l` it seems that most of the data is in the Windows part. Awkard 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Windows partition occupies `708.5GB`. You could either shrink it (it's **unsafe**, make backups first and verify they are **valid**) or you could mount and use it for storage. After you shrink it, you'll have to shuffle and resize your Linux partitions which is also **unsafe**, so again **backup first**.